# Append text to a file after a certain match

Tags: ruby

I'd like to append a new text to a file, but only after some existing match.

To append a text, currently I am doing something like:

```
File.open(path/to/file, 'a') { |file| file.puts(text) }
```

But this always appends `text` at the end of the file.

Is there a way to append `text` after certain string in the text, rather than at the end of the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sub` or `gsub` to search and replace matches, e.g.

```
file_contents = File.read(file_name)
file_contents.gsub!(/hello/, "hello #{text}")
File.write(file_name, file_contents)
```

See http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-write